# Where can I find the Texture tab?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have recently downloaded blender 2.72b and am having trouble finding how to texture objects. I have tried to look up videos about it but they all seem to have the Texture tab, in the Properties panel, whereas mine is off-screen and I can't get it on screen.

How can I get to this tab?

Comment: I have tried to look up videos about it but they all seem to have the texture button whereas mine is offscreen and I can't get it on screen

Comment: I want to texture a house on the blender renderer

Comment: I have built the house but its the standard grey

Comment: Not very just brick and slate for the roof

Comment: Try pressing the middle mouse button and dragging/scrolling, while over the list of tabs, in the Properties panel, to be able to scroll to the Texture tab.

Comment: Tank you so much guys for helping

Comment: @SamuelMortimer did that solve it?

Comment: @SamuelMortimer Do my edits and answer meet the your goals?

Answer (score 5):

The Texture tab can be found in the Properties panel, but in the default state of the interface, it may not be accessible; What you need to do is to simply hover your mouse over the list of tabs in this panel, in the top, and use the Mouse Wheel to either scroll, on press it's button and drag.

Answer (score 2):

To the **Right** of your screen is the **Properties** panel, the *textures* are an option that you can select under the **Properties** panel.

If you can't find it, mouse over the tab list until you see the textures; they look like checks.

[image]

You said this was off-screen for you, try maximizing the blender program, you may have moved it.